# How can we prove this integral inequality?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, convex-analysis

There is the first inequality that I should solve:
For all $R>0$
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-R\sin(\varphi)}d\varphi < \frac\pi{2R}(1 - e^{-R})$$

But in the next exercise, there is a more general case: if $f''(x) < 0 $ on $[a, b]$, then 
$$ \int_a^b e^{-\lambda f(x)} dx < \frac{b-a}{\lambda(f(b) - f(a))}(e^{-\lambda f(b)} - e^{-\lambda f(a)}) $$

First of all I think that i should apply Jensen's inequality for integrals, because $ e^{-\lambda f(x)} $ is convex function, when $ f''(x) < 0 $. But it is 
provide me wrong inequation ( $\int >= $ something). So I don't know what to do. Please help me solve this inequality.

Comment: $\frac{2\theta}{\pi} \leqslant \sin \theta \leqslant \theta$ on $[0,\pi/2]$

Comment: @RRL , I think this can't help, because in right part we have R in the denominator.

Comment: But when we integrate $e^{-R\varphi}$ we divide by a factor of $R$ by the chain rule.

Comment: @PeterForeman, Thanks, I forgot about this. But what about second inequation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\lambda > 0$. Since $f''(x) < 0$ on $[a, b]$, it lies upper than the line segment given by equation $g(x)=f(a)+\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}(x-a)$. Therefore, $\forall x\in[a,b]:f(x)\geqslant g(x) \implies e^{-\lambda f(x)} \leqslant e^{-\lambda g(x)}$. From monotony of the Riemann integral we obtain:
\begin{equation} \int_a^b{e^{-\lambda f(x)}dx}<\int_a^b{e^{-\lambda g(x)}dx}=\frac{b-a}{\lambda{(f(b)-f(a))}}(e^{-\lambda f(a)}-e^{-\lambda f(b)}). \end{equation}

Comment: (+1) All to easy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

For first inequality consider the function g(x)=2x/pi , because sin(x) is concave in 
(0,pi/2) then we have that sin(x) >= g(x), thus e^(-Rsin(x)) <= e^(-2Rx/pi) and integrating you get the result.

Comment: Thanks. It is right solution, but only on the first part, And now I don't know how to apply this to the second part

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected those mistakes, thanks.